# GKE ingress not routing based on host in the url

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I created the following ingress for my service on GKE (it's part of a helm chart with variables)

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: TestIngress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: {{ $ingressExternalStaticIpName }}
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "web.frontend.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: {{ $webServiceName }}
            port:
              number: 80
  - host: "grpc.frontend.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: {{ $grpcServiceName }}
            port:
              number: 80
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: {{ $grpcServiceName }}
      port:
        number: 80
```

I modified the /etc/hosts to make web.frontend.com point to the static ip. then I ran

```
curl web.frontend.com
```

I realize the grpc service was responding to my request. I read this doc https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/ and it saids it routes based on the Host header?? that sounds a bit weird since I assumed host meant the url. so I tried

```
curl -H "Host:web.frontend.com:80" web.frontend.com
```

and still got response from grpc server

How exactly does ingress host work, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Which static IP you're using for static routing ? And is the request reaching the cluster ? Are you getting any errors, or the problem is getting requests from the grpc server even after modifying?

Coming to ingress host, as noted in the doc that is being referred, it is an optional value for the ingress http rule to identify which hosts does the rule apply for. If not host is mentioned, then that rule will apply to all incoming HTTP requests.

Comment: It working after trying it the next day. I think it's some caching done by google that caused this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried it the next day and it's working. The issue might be due to google caching